# Can no longer open multiple VLC players

Tags: vlc

Since upgrading to 14.04 I seem to be limited to one VLC player only ?!? ( went slowly up each upgrade from 12.04)

Comment: I have always been able to get multiple players when opening files from a file window.  New files now only open up into the VLC player that was already open. It is beyond frustrating to work a certain way for years, only to have core functionality in my process so drastically removed with no reasoning I can fathom. Short story is: I am now restricted to one VLC player (and one Videos player) maximum and that is all i can get.  I would sometimes have six to eight players open as i worked with different aspects of art and research projects.  Please help me with some good news. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions 2.1.x playing multiple VLC instances and different streams in each is as easy as clicking tools -> Preferences... (or just press ctrl+p)(note this does not exist on the Mac version):

in Interface tab scroll down to playlist and instances

untick checkbox Allow only one instance

untick checkbox use only one instance when started from file manager

Press Save.

Source: https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/

Comment: Thankyou jahedev.  Yes I feel suitably thick :) I must have looked at that tab a half dozen times and just blanked out completely evry time. Good thing I have a sense of humour and can laugh at myself.  Thanks again.